# loop goes to next occurence after one match

Tags: arrays, perl, matching

I have an array that I am using to match against another table.  When I execute it, it grabs only the first occurrence.  For example, if company1 is in my array, it will grab only the first instance of company1 and then go to the next search term, say company2.  If there had been a company1.0 after company1, only company1 would be spit out.  I want it to spit out company1 etc.\t company1.0 and so on on the same line, as there will be multiple matches between the two lists.

Here is my code:

```
my @attendees = ('company');
foreach $fbm (@attendees) {
    open(RFILE, '<', "file.txt")
    or die "no such file posf: $!";

    while ( $line = <RFILE> )
    { 
        if ($line =~ /$fbm/i)
        {
            print $fbm."\t". $line;
            last;
        }
        if (eof(RFILE)) 
        {
            print "posf"."\n";
        }               
    }
}
print STDERR "\n\nFINISHED!!";
```

My Input:

```
company1
company1.0
company1 also begins with 1 but different ending
company1 can i have this one too?
```

My output:company1
Desired output: company1\tcompany1.0\tcompany1 also begins with 1 but different ending\tcompany1 can i have this one too?

Comment: oh yeah...company1 should be in the array not just 'company'

Comment: one more clarification, for input, between each company name there is a new line.

Comment: Just edit your question and make the changes you mention here, it would be easier to read.

Comment: There is only a single element in your array. How do you expect more output ?

Comment: yes, ok, say there were more...this is just an example...but regardless, if there is company1 in my array and it occurs on every line, is there a way to spit out every instance instead of just the first?

Comment: You probably need to re-open the file, your `while( $line = <RFILE> )` line will exhaust all of the input from your file. So next time around your *for* loop there is nothing to read.

Comment: hmm...im a little new to arrays, where is an appropriate place to re-open the file? is there better option than RFILE?

Comment: my mistake, you do reopen the file each time in the for loop.

Comment: My guess is that the `last` was supposed to happen when `eof` fired. Of course that makes the `while` loop pretty non-sensical. Is this some sort of translation from `C` done by somebody who didn't bother to read up on Perl before doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
my @attendees = ('company');
my @whatever;
open ( my $fh, '<', "file.txt")
    or die "could not open file.txt: $!";

while ( <$fh> ) {
    chomp $_;
    push @whatever, $_;
}

foreach my $attendee ( @attendees ) {
     foreach my $thing ( @whatever ) { 
        if ($thing =~ /$attendee/i) {
            print $attendee, "\t", $thing, "\n";
        }
    }
}
print STDERR "FINISHED!\n";
```

Perhaps this does what you want it to, but I must admit that I'm not quite sure.

Comment: well thanks a lot...it seems more sensible for what I am trying to do, i will give it a go!

Comment: what is the my @whatever; representing? just the content of my file?

Comment: Yes. I couldn't figure out what it might contain so I gave the variable a name that expressed my knowledge.

Comment: Instead of the nested foreach loops, why not just? `push @whatever, $_ if grep {/$_/} @attendees;`

Comment: Because I don't have a clue what this is supposed to do.

Comment: all i am trying to do is search a list with this array.  If there is a match print it in the order of my array..if there is another occurence of this match, print that as well...